# Number of Max Instances Per Core in ArcGIS Server

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-10.5

ArcGIS Server 10.5 Windows

This question has been beat to death, but like others have said, documentation is hard to follow and described differently in places.  I understand all of the concepts and what is done, so I am hoping this is a simple question.

For a service, in some cases max instances can be set to n + 1 (n number of cores).

Does this mean for a 3 machine site with 4 cores on each machine the number is 12 + 1, or 4 + 1?

E.g. 4 cores each of three machines

4  x 3 + 1 = 13 max instances
or
4 + 1 = 5 max instances.

Comment: If you configure 13 instances on a 4-core host, you'll not enjoy the result.

Comment: That is what I think as well, but I want to confirm that is regardless of the number machines involved in the entire site.

Comment: The number in the instances (min and max) is the number in *each* Server site.  The load on a enterprise geodatabase with 5 max instances with 3 sites could be 15 connections.  The load on an enterprise geodatabase with 13 max instances across 3 sites would be 39 connections.  It's probably not wise to exceed the number of cores if you have a large number of services which will busy at one time, since a single client could chew on all of them (plus some) to pull multiple tiles in parallel.